# Creating Popup menu or modal dialog box in Dimple.js by Clicking any Values

Tags: jquery, d3.js, dimple.js

I have created a bar chart using dimple.js and I want to know if popup box can be added on it. I have tried using alert box and window box which I got it and I couldn't find any popup or modal box examples. Is there any way for adding Popup or modal Dialog box on dimple.js. Please confirm it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look into how questions should be asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask